# Error When updating Database Date/Time format from Vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite, sql-update

I am using an update query written in a VB.Net which is then sent to an SQLite Client. Everything is working fine when updating except for dates. I have 2 Date/time pickers on a VB form. I take there values and trim them left,10 so i only have the date and put it in a variable. Then i put it in a query and it should send to the database client. Instead of putting in the date it wipes the value and leave it blank! Any idea as to why this is? Code is below!

```
Sub Cmd_SaveClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Create checkbox text

    DOB_DTP = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(dtp_DOB.Value, 10)
    DBS_DTP = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(dtp_DBS.Value, 10)

    'DBS
    If cb_DBS.Checked = True Then
        DBS = "T"
    Else
        DBS = "F"
    End If

    'MONDAY
    If CB_Monday.Checked = True Then
        Monday = "T"
    Else
        Monday = "F"
    End If

    'TUESDAY
    If CB_Tuesday.Checked = True Then
        Tue = "T"
    Else
        Tue = "F"
    End If

    'WEDNESDAY
    If CB_Wednesday.Checked = True Then
        Wed = "T"
    Else
        Wed = "F"
    End If

    'THURSDAY
    If CB_Thursday.Checked = True Then
        Thur = "T"
    Else
        Thur = "F"
    End If

    'FRIDAY
    If CB_Friday.Checked = True Then
        Fri = "T"
    Else
        Fri = "F"
    End If

    'Update into Database
    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

    SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET Staff_Surname = '" & txt_Surname.Text & "' , Staff_First_Name = '" & txt_Firstname.Text & "' , Staff_DOB = '" & DOB_DTP & "' , Staff_Contact_No_1 = '" & txt_Contact_1.Text & "' , Staff_Contact_No_2 = '" & txt_Contact_2.Text & "', Staff_Email = '" & txt_email.Text & "' , DBS_Check = '" & DBS & "' , DBS_Renew_Date = '" & DBS_DTP & "' , Work_Monday = '" & Monday & "' , Work_Tuesday = '" & Tue & "' , Work_Wednesday = '" & Wed & "' , Work_Thursday = '" & Thur & "' , Work_Friday = '" & Fri & "' WHERE Username = '"  & Change_Password.Password.usernamechange & "'"

    SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    SQLcommand.Dispose()

    MsgBox("Saved!",vbInformation,"Saved!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you check with breakpoints what's returning in the variable 'DOB_DTP'?

Comment: that code hurts my eyes, so I have to say: `Fri = CB_Friday.Checked` is all you need for those DOW vars

Comment: Yes checked with break points! and Sorry Plutonix i'm only an A-Level student! Been programming SQL for less then a month and VB.net just under a year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stongly recomend you build the command using [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
mySqlcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [TABLENAME] SET [COLUMN1] = @COLUMN1, [COLUMN2] = @COLUMN2 WHERE [ID] = @ID;"
mySqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@COLUMN1", DBNull.Value))
mySqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@COLUMN2", DBNull.Value))
mySqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", 1))
```

Then, the API will take care of all the formatting.

Comment: I've never used these before! It's for a school project! :S

Comment: It says SqlParameter is not defined!

Comment: You must import the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Btw, you should create the date parameters like this: `New SqlParameter("@DATECOLUMN", myDateTimePicker.Value)`where "DATECOLUMN" is the name of the column.

Comment: What does import namespace mean? I need it dumbing down! It's a school project!

Comment: I used this Code, is it correct?
SQLcommand.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Staff_DOB", dtp_DOB.Value)

Comment: It enables type names to be referenced without namespace qualification. Example: If you want to declare a form and you put `Imports System.Windows.Forms` at top of you page, you could just type `Dim f As Form`. If this namespace is not imported you'll have to type `Dim f As System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Comment: Sir, you are a legend! I have got in working! Thank you soo much!